# multistep form - toggle between styled radio buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, jquery

i have built a multi step form that works , but it is not very "elegant" coded, 
  so i am asking 
for your advice to make it more efficient ,
i have placed here only 2 steps out of 3 because the first step - email name etc', is not relevant for my question:

in each step 2 and 3 there are 2 styled radio button yes and no for the user to select,
in each step i need to toggle between check and uncheck styled images and of course prevnt that both 
yes and no check images will show at the same time.

i know that the default/not styled radio buttons behavior prevents two checked buttons at the same time- can i use it here to save some lines of code?

**the html(index.php)**

```
   <form method="post"  id="userForm" action="process_form.php">
<fieldset class="formFieldset">
   <div id="second_step" class="vanish">
      <div class="form  slide_two check_wrap">
         <div class="quizyes quizbtn">
           <img class="uncheck_pic  pic  one"  src="images/check_not.png">
           <img class="check_pic  pic  agree"  src="images/check_bgfull.png" style="display: none;">
           <h1 class="quizText">yes</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="quizno quizbtn">
           <img class="uncheck_pic   pic  two"  src="images/check_not.png">
           <img class="check_pic not  not_agree pic first_not"  src="images/check_bgfull.png" style="display: none;">
           <h1 class="quizText">no</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="feedback_wrap"><div class="feedback"></div></div>
         <div id="submit_wrap" >
            <input type="radio" class="yep decideOne" val ="1" name="yep"   style="display: none;"/>
            <input type="radio" class="nope decideOne" val ="2" name="nope"   style="display: none;"/>
         </div>
    </div></div>

                                          <!-- end of second step -->
    <!--  third step -->
  <div id="third_step" class="vanish">
    <div class="form check_wrap">
        <div class="quizyes quizbtn">
            <img class="uncheck_pic  pic  one"  src="images/check_not.png">
            <img class="check_pic pic  agree"  src="images/check_bgfull.png" style="display: none;">
            <h1 class="quizText">yes</h1>
           </div>
        <div class="quizno quizbtn">
            <img class="uncheck_pic pic two"  src="images/check_not.png">
            <img class="check_pic not not_agree pic second_not"  src="images/check_bgfull.png" style="display: none;">
            <h1 class="quizText">no</h1>
         </div>
        <div id="feedback_wrap"><div class="feedback"></div></div>
            <div id="submit_wrap">
                <input type="radio" class="yep decideTwo" val ="1" name="yep"   style="display: none;"/>
                <input type="radio" class="nope decideTwo" val ="2" name="nope"  style="display: none;"/>
                </div>                                  
        </div></div>
            <!-- end of third step -->

            </fieldset>
                <div id="submit_wrap">
            <input class="submit btn" type="button" name="submit_all" id="submit_all" value="" />
            </div>
                </form>
```

**the script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
    $('.check_pic').hide();
    //original field values
    var isDecide= false;
    //toggle images and set values
$('.pic').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('uncheck_pic') && $(this).hasClass('one') ){ 
                     $(".yep").val('agree');
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).siblings('.check_pic').show();
                    $(".not").hide();
                    $(".two").show();
            } 
    else if ($(this).hasClass('uncheck_pic') && $(this).hasClass('two') ){ 
                    var isDecide = $(".nope").val('notagree');
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).siblings('.check_pic').show();
                    $('.agree').hide();
                     $(".one").show();
            }       
    else if ($(this).hasClass('check_pic') && $(this).hasClass('agree') ){ 
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).siblings('.uncheck_pic').show();
            }       
    else if ($(this).hasClass('check_pic') && $(this).hasClass('not_agree') ){ 
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).siblings('.uncheck_pic').show();
            }       
});
    // start the submit thing

    $('#submit_all').click(function() {
       if($('#second_step').is(":visible")) {
          $('.decideOne').removeClass('error valid');

       // prevent empty boxes and display a message

       if($('.one').is(":visible") && $('.two').is(":visible")) {
        $('.feedback').text('please select one').show();
        return false;
            }
               // case the user selects yes
       if($('.agree').is(":visible")) {
          $('.feedback').text('thank you for selecting yes').show();
             var isDecide = $(".yep").val();
             var name = $("#firstname").val();
             var phone = $("#phone").val();
             var email = $("#email").val();
              var dataString = 'user-details:name=' + name + ' phone=' + phone + ' email=' + email + ' decide=' +  isDecide ;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/",
                data: dataString,
                success : function(data) {
                console.log('data');
                $('#second_step').delay(1000).fadeOut(600, function() {
                $('#first_step').fadeIn(400);
                $('.feedback').hide();
            });
                }
            }); 
               }
                     // case the user selects no
        if($('.first_not').is(":visible")) {
            $(".yep").val();
            $(".nope").val();
            $('#second_step').fadeOut(600, function() {
                $('#third_step').fadeIn(600);
                $('.feedback').hide();
            });
        }
        return false;

// end second step

    } else if($('#third_step').is(":visible")) {

        $('.third_input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');
      // prevent empty boxes and display a message 
      if($('.quizyes .one').is(":visible") && $('.quizno .two').is(":visible")) {
        $('.feedback').text('please select one').show();
        return false;
    }
     // if decide yes then submit
      if($('.agree').is(":visible")) {
      $('.feedback').text('thank you for selecting yes').show();
         var isDecide = $(".yep").val();
         var name = $("#firstname").val();
         var phone = $("#phone").val();
         var email = $("#email").val();
          var dataString = 'user-details:name=' + name + ' phone=' + phone + ' email=' + email + ' decide=' +  isDecide ;
      $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/",
            data: dataString,
            success : function(data) {
            console.log('data');
            $('#second_step').delay(1000).fadeOut(600, function() {
            $('#first_step').fadeIn(400);
            $('.feedback').hide();
                });
            }
                });//end ajax 
         return true;   
        }//end if agree is visible

        // if decide no then send message and quit
        if($(".second_not").is(":visible")) {
            $(".nope").val("no");
            $('.feedback').text('too bad bye bye').show();
                $('#third_step').fadeOut(3000, function() {
                $('#first_step').fadeIn(600);
                $('.feedback').hide();
            });
        }
                }
        // end third step

        });
        //end submit_all

    }) // general function
  }); // document ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude my wish to you take a look on good js library - knockout to represants all that kind show, hide functunality and forms inputs, checkbox, radiobutton modifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using images to style your radiobuttons I would suggest combining the images into a [Sprite](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and just using css to move the background-position of the image using the **input[type=radio]:checked** selector. No javascript necessary.

**For Example** - you combine your two images into a single image that is 100px wide, each individual image being 50px wide. And then style the checkbox...

```
input[type=radio].myCustomRadioButton {
  background: url(myRadioButtonSprite.png) 0 0;
}

input[type=radio].myCustomRadioButton:checked {
  background-position: -50px 0;
}
```

Assuming your images are lined up horizontally in your sprite, this would move the background image of the radiobutton left 50px to display the checked-image, when the radiobutton is checked.

As a side note, doing this is going to require unsetting some of the browser styling that is going to occur automatically. A good reset for form elements is to start with these styles.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
```

Comment: radio buttons not check boxes:) and thank you it looks like a good idea to get more efficient code, but how sprites/bg position  behave in mobile? because its responsive website.second thing if i understand you correctly if one radio button is checked it doesnt prevent the other to be checked like the default behavior of radio buttons?

Comment: See the mobile tab under Browser Compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Comment: oops, radio buttons. updated it, but everything still applies

Comment: thank you again that you took the time to post your answer! ,its efficient but it doesnt answer my radion button question and creates cross browsers issues.

Comment: This method does not create cross-browser issues. It's a very common method. How doesn't it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if you need to support Internet Explorer versions less than 9, the `:checked` pseudo-selector isn't available in pure CSS and you may need to resort to some scripting.

Listen for the `change` event on your custom radio buttons and update a parent element based on that.

[Here's an example.](http://jsbin.com/iKaXUqU/1/edit?html,css,js,output)
The `<input>` has `position: absolute` so the `clip` property can be applied to hide it and it does not affect the content box of its parent, which has `relative` position to contain it.

I used `background-color` but you could swap this in for your image urls or change the `background-position` of a sprite as suggested in [rob-gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18802212/1247130).

You can still add visible label text inside the label as you see in the second set of radio inputs.